# How to quickly approximate the eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $A$, is there any algorithm that can quickly approximate all of its eigenvectors? By "quickly", I mean with time complexity less than $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.